# Forces field Wind does not affect hair

Tags: particles, physics, hair, force-fields

everytime I try to add wind in my scene the hair is still static. Only if I move the wind object the hair is moving. 
But if I dont do that the hair goes in the right direction but doesnt move. I have this problem in Blender 2.80, 2.83 and 2.79.
I have a simple plane with a hair particle system. I have this problem with Vortex and the Turbulence too. Same problem with hairs on characters.

[image]

[image]

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

A wind force field makes a steady, laminar stream of wind. This is not desirable because that way all the hair moves in the same direction. In order to fix this, add a turbulence force field in front of the wind.

The turbulence force field will disrupt airflow. However, this disruption is still constant meaning that the hairs will shift a little, but will remain in the position. However, if you press <kbd>G</kbd> to move the turbulence, it will change the appearance of the hairs.

[image]

In order to make the turbulence dynamic, select the force field and keyframe animate its rotation. Please note that only animating X and Y rotation will work, and not Z.

I hope this helps!